# $_FILES super global variable

Tags: php, file, superglobals

why doesn't the unset function remove $_FILES contents or empty it after uploading a file .
how can I empty my $FILES variable after uploading a file .

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Files Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="pdf" id="pdf"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="upload">
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
unset($GLOBALS['$_FILES']);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";
?>

The Output is :
array(1) {
  ["pdf"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(19) "Courses Degrees.pdf"
    ["type"]=>
    string(15) "application/pdf"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php6BBD.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(624129)
  }
}
```

Comment: If you `var_dump($GLOBALS);`, you'll see that the files is under `_FILES`, not `$FILES`

Comment: Your edit still has the dollar sign on _FILES

Comment: I have already tried all of these

Comment: You have tried `$_GLOBALS['_FILES']`? Hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the key of the variable

```
unset($_FILES['key']);
```

Your key is probably "pdf" when looking at your output

```
unset($_FILES['pdf']);
```

Comment: I want to remove all keys with one step

Comment: You have an array of arrays. The first row of ```$_FILES``` ("pdf") contains all of your different files.

Comment: Thank you .. this is true